# Migrate a Redhat VM to Azure with ASR mode

Tags: linux, azure, redhat

I have a VM Redhat Centos 5.6.
I would like to migrate it to Azure in ASR mode for time and cost reasons: my deployed web application exposes a web service (server Apache Tomcat 5.5).

Here are my VM properties:

- $cat /proc/version
  Linux version 2.6.18-238.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)) #1 SMP Thu Jan 13 16:24:47 EST 2011
- $cat /etc/redhat-release
  CentOS release 5.6 (Final)
- $uname -a
  Linux fuspplbe01 2.6.18-238.el5 #1 SMP Thu Jan 13 16:24:47 EST 2011 **i686 i686 i386** GNU/Linux

Is it possible to migrate my VM to Azure in ASR Mode?
I did not find documentation to do it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Please view the below document from microsoft, if you OS version falls into the category then you can surely replicate your on premise virtual machine.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-support-matrix

You can also launch a support ticket if you face any issues in replication. Do let me know if this helped you.

Updated Answer:

If the OS Version does not falls into the list what you can do is convert that vhdx disk (dont know the vmware disks extension) and convert that to .vhd and upload it to azure and build a VM from that disk, and see if everything works fine or not